# How to customize the 1st and 3rd cell in a custom collection view

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a ui collection view returning custom cells of posted images - I want to round the corners of only the 1st and 3rd cell in the top row returned and nothing else. I checked the indexPath but is the same for multiple cells so it rounds multiple rows of cells.

Comment: "I checked the indexPath but is the same for multiple cells so it rounds multiple rows of cells." Cells are reused. That means the same cell will reappear later slotted into a different index path. So you must round the cell for the 1st and 3rd index path but _unround_ the cell for all others. Otherwise they will all end up rounded.

Comment: YAY THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! It worked!! This all makes sense now.. I didn't realized how they were re-used

Answer (score 0):

I would add the customization inside `willDisplayCell` :

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,  willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   if indexPath.row == 1 || indexPath.row == 3 {
      cell.roundCorners() // or whatever code you use for this.
   }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work as the indexPath.row is repeated for multiple cells

Comment: Ah, try `indexPath.item` instead.